# selecting contents inside roundbracket using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to get the contents inside a round braket,

for example.. if we have content like `var str="test exp (content needed)"`

I am trying to make the str value as "content needed"; how do I achieve it using regular expression? and I wanna see the condition if the string has more than one occurences of round brackets like `var str="test exp (content needed) test (tst)"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var m = /\(([^)]*)\)/.exec(str);
str = m[1];
```

Just a note: remember that for simple cases it's better to use regular string methods, like `indexOf` and `substring`, because they're usually faster and way clearer for you. For example:

```
var i1 = str.indexOf("("), i2 = str.indexOf(")");
str = str.substring(i1, i2);
```

If you want to match all the sequences between parentheses, you can try this:

```
var m = str.match(/\([^)]*\)/g);
```

Now `m` contains all the content between parentheses, *including* the parentheses. If you want to get just the inner content, try this:

```
m = m.map(function(match) {return match.slice(1, -1);});
```

Remember that this doesn't work for IE8 and older, because it doesn't support the `map` mathod for arrays. Either use a polyfill, or a classic `for` loop.

Comment: what if there are more than one occurences of round brackets.. m[1] is not a generic method